# Number of ways to combine $n$ distinct objects into $r$ unlabeled groups

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

For example, if I have objects a, b and c and want to arrange them into 2 groups. The possible combinations are

[a b c] and [ ];

[a b] and [c];

[a c] and [b];

[b c] and [a];

Is there a formula that governs this? Again, the objects themselves are distinct but the groups are not.

Comment: Sounds like "partitions," of which formulas exist.

Comment: @SeanRoberson or compositions.

Comment: At the risk of pointing out the obvious, the sets $\{a, b\}$ and $\{c\}$ are distinct.  The groups are not labeled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are the [Sterling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) $S(n,r)$ that count the number of ways to partition $n$ distinct objects into $r$ **nonempty** subsets (*blocks*). Since you are admitting empty blocks the numbers you are after would be
$$S'(n,r):=\sum_{k=1}^rS(n,k)\ .$$

Comment: Thanks! Instead of this specialized Stirling number, would the Bell number for a set of three objects (following the example) work to include the empty sets?

Comment: @ShaneXavier: If $r=n-1$ you can of course use the Bell number $B_n$ and deduct $1$ for the partition into $n$ blocks.